# UML from code not showing relationship to List of Interface

Tags: visual-studio, interface, uml

I'm generating a UML Class Diagram for this code in Visual Studio 2013:

```
interface IParent
{
    IChild Child { get; set; }
}

interface IChild
{
    List<IChildren> Grandkids {get; set; }
}

interface IChildren
{

}
```

I didn't get what I expected.  What I saw was this:

[image]

However I would have thought the relationship between IChild and IChildren would have been indicated somehow but instead it's on it's own.

Why is this?

Comment: Can't talk for VS but other tools have this problem too. Likely code inspection is not that easy and they leave it to the user to verify/correct the disassembled code.

Comment: That's disappointing since the connection is pretty damned obvious.